# How to assign members to groups iterating a CSV file

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to assign members to Azure Active Directory groups after creating them using Terraform and the resources "azuread_group_member", "azuread_group" and "azuread_user".

First of all, I have a CSV file that has a relationship between users and departments:

```
first_name,last_name,department
UserName1,LastName1,Department1
UserName2,LastName2,Department2
```

And other CSV file containing the groups:

```
department_name
Department1
Department2
```

Then, I have a local variable that is reading these CSV files:

```
locals {
    users = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/users.csv"))
    groups = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/aad_groups.csv"))
}
```

Next, I create the users:

```
# Create users
resource "azuread_user" "users" {
for_each = { for user in local.users : user.first_name =\> user }

    user_principal_name = format(
        "%s@%s",
        each.value.employee_id,
        "mydomain.com"
        )

}
```

Following, I create the groups iterating the groups.csv

```
# Create groups resource
"azuread_group" "groups" {
for_each = { for group in local.groups : group.deparment_name => group }
display_name = each.value.deparment_name
security_enabled = true }
```

But now, I would like assign members, with "azuread_group_member" to the groups using the relationship that I have in users.csv, in the column "department"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created users and groups as below.

```
locals {
  users = {
    "john@xxumail.onmicrosoft.com" = { first_name = "John", last_name = "Doe" , password = "xxx@123",department = "Marketing Department" },
    "jane@xxxxmail.onmicrosoft.com" = { first_name = "Jane", last_name = "Doe" , password = "xxx@123",department = "IT Department"}
  }
}

locals {
    groups = {
    "Marketing Department" = { display_name = "Marketing Department" },
    "Sales Department"     = { display_name = "Sales Department" },
    "IT Department"        = { display_name = "IT Department" }
  }
}

resource "azuread_user" "users" {
  for_each = local.users

  display_name         = "${each.value.first_name} ${each.value.last_name}"
  mail_nickname        = each.value.first_name
  user_principal_name = each.key
  password = each.value.password
  department = each.value.department
}



resource "azuread_group" "departments" {
  for_each = local.groups

  display_name = each.value.display_name
  security_enabled = true 
  mail_enabled =false
}
```

[image]

[image]

Here note that group key value must match the user department value.

***example : Marketing Department  , which equals user department of John Doe***

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "group_members" {
  for_each = local.users

  group_object_id = azuread_group.departments[each.value.department].object_id
  member_object_id = azuread_user.users[each.key].object_id
}
```

[image]

With the above mapping i could add the users based on their department to groups .

[image]

[image]